# Data dump - available login data?

Tags: feature-request, login, data-dump, privacy

I am currently working on a project with the Stack Exchange data. To get more insight it would be great if I could get the login times for each user, not only the dates of comments, posts, etc...

Does anyone know, if and where such data is available? Or is it an issue of private information to get this data?

Comment: Sure, why not IP address and credit card number?

Comment: Doesn't the data-sump have LastAccessDate in the users table?

Comment: I logged in once. I haven't been asked to log back in since then.

Comment: @Andy I guess OP means visit times, i.e. when each user visited a site and for how long.

Answer (score 4):

No, that isn't available and it shouldn't be.

I wouldn't want to make that public myself. When someone is online can reveal their patterns. If made public, this could end up in the wrong hands and bad things could happen (if you'd know when I am at work or not for example).

Comment: (+1) `bad things could happen`. VERY BAD THINGS CAN HAPPEN !

Answer (score 3):

I'm frankly a little shocked that you even ask this. Revealing this information would be horrible for privacy, actually illegal in many countries and pretty antithetical to the approach StackExchange takes to protecting sensitive user information (and asides from the passwords and login names, exact meta data on visits is the most private sensitive information there is)

A hundred things could go bad with that, people can use it to stage robberies (by easily finding out the user's patterns and thus their daily commute, for instance), stalkers could gain detailed insight on the daily lives of their victims, ruthless companies could harvest and sell this information on mass (website usage patterns are valuable) and so many more that an exhaustive list would probably break the char limit in an answer.

**To summarize: No, you cannot. Nor should you ever be able to.**